# Infinite autoscroll img html resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an img autoscroll infinity in html and css. This are the codes I used:

```css
@keyframes ani{
0%{background-position: 0 0;}
100%{background-position: 1000000vw 0;}
}
div.map {background:url(https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arianagrande/images/7/70/Example.png/revision/latest?cb=20160301231046) repeat-x 0 / 100% auto;
height:500px;
animation: ani 100000s linear infinite ;
}
```

```html
<div class="map"></div>
```

And for most parts it works fine, but since the width is set to 100% automatically, when resized there's a lot of blank space under the image? Any idea how to get rid of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to cover 100% of width and maintain aspect ratio and also cover the 100% height in same time! I think covering 100% of height is a better choice when you have infinite horizontal scroll.

Comment: So its impossible to use it without ruining the rest of the webpage? I think I'll just make a gif then lol

Comment: I mean 100% height of its container not rest of the page. let the width to be auto.